# This is my first project in python. I want to ensure allocated values for the budget category(Food,Cloth& Entertainment) is not greater than self.amtt

Tags: python

```
class budgetapp():

    def __init__(self,Deposit_amtt, Food, Cloth, Entertainment):
        self.amtt = Deposit_amtt
        self.Food = Food
        self.Cloth = Cloth
        self.Entertainment = Entertainment

    def withdrawal(self):

        for i in range (0,1):
            print('Press 1 for Food\n')

            print('Press 2 for Cloth\n')

            print('Press 3 for Entertainment\n')

        choice = int(input('Which Budget Category do you want to withdraw From?: '))

        if choice == 1:
            
            amt_withdrawal = float(input("How Much do you want to withdraw: "))
        
            if amt_withdrawal>=0 and amt_withdrawal<= self.Food:
                print("Withdrawal Successful")

            elif amt_withdrawal > self.Food:
                print("Insufficient Balance")
            
            else:
                print("Negative values cannot be withdrawn")

        elif choice == 2:

            amt_withdrawal = float(input("How Much do you want to withdraw: "))
            
        
            if amt_withdrawal>=0 and amt_withdrawal<= self.Cloth:
                print("Withdrawal Successful")

            elif amt_withdrawal > self.Cloth:
                print("Insufficient Balance")

            else:
                print("Negative values cannot be withdrawn")

        elif choice == 3:
        
            amt_withdrawal = float(input("How Much do you want to withdraw: "))
        
            if amt_withdrawal>=0 and amt_withdrawal<= self.Entertainment:
                print("Withdrawal Successful")

            elif amt_withdrawal > self.Entertainment:
                print("Insufficient Balance")
            
            else:
                print("Negative values cannot be withdrawn")

        else:  
            print('Invalid choice. Options are between 1-3 only')


budg = budgetapp(float(input("Enter an amount to deposit: ")),
                 float(input("What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to food: ")), 
                 float(input("What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to cloth: ")),
                 float(input("What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to Entertainment: ")))
budg.withdrawal()
```

Comment: You need to ask a question. Is there something that doesn't work?  Do you get an error? Or wrong result?

Comment: 1) You're not checking if the withdrawal is greater than the balance i.e. self.amtt, and 2) You're not updating the remaining budget for a category and the balance if a withdrawal is successful (e.g. self.amtt  and self.Food).

Comment: In constructor the amounts for Food, Clothing, etc. are percentage of total.  You need to convert them to dollars based upon the deposit amount e.g. `self.Food= Deposit_amtt * Food/100.`

Comment: Is this enough for you to make the corrections?

Comment: I am trying to implement your first analysis

How can i show you the adjustment i made? I only added a new conditional statement within the constructor but it's not making much difference.

Comment: I would suggest modifying your posted code with your update and then asking a question about what problem you are now having.

Comment: I added an answer to show you my suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Tips on your code:

- Use [Python Style Guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) naming convention
- Constructor (i.e. method **init**)

  - Food, Clothing, and Entertainment allowances are Percent of the deposit amount
  - convert these from percent to amounts
  - Check that percent totals to 100
  - Raise an exception if it does not
- Method withdrawal

  - Show balance with each choice option
  - Check sufficient funds for withdrawal
  - Update balance if withdrawal is successful

**Code**

```
class BudgetApp:

    def __init__(self,deposit_amt, food, cloth, entertainment):
        self.balance = deposit_amt
        
        if food + cloth + entertainment == 100:
            self.food = food * deposit_amt / 100.
            self.cloth = cloth * deposit_amt / 100.
            self.entertainment = entertainment * deposit_amt / 100.
        else:
            raise Exception("food, cloth, entertainment percent should sum to 100")

    def withdrawal(self):
        
        choice = int(input(f'''
        Which Budget Category do you want to withdraw from?: 
            Please Enter:
                1 for Food (balance: {self.food:.2f})
                2 for Cloth (balance: {self.cloth:.2f})
                3 for Entertainment (balance: {self.entertainment:.2f})'''))

        if choice == 1:
            
            amt_withdrawal = float(input("How Much do you want to withdraw: "))
        
            if 0 < amt_withdrawal <= self.food:
                self.balance -= amt_withdrawal
                self.food -= amt_withdrawal
                print("Withdrawal Successful")

            elif amt_withdrawal > self.food:
                print("Insufficient Food Balance")
            
            else:
                print("Negative values cannot be withdrawn")

        elif choice == 2:

            amt_withdrawal = float(input("How Much do you want to withdraw: "))
            
            if 0 < amt_withdrawal <= self.cloth:
                self.balance -= amt_withdrawal
                self.cloth -= amt_withdrawal
                print("Withdrawal Successful")

            elif amt_withdrawal > self.cloth:
                print("Insufficient Cloth Balance")

            else:
                print("Negative values cannot be withdrawn")

        elif choice == 3:
        
            amt_withdrawal = float(input("How Much do you want to withdraw: "))
        
            if 0 < amt_withdrawal <= self.entertainment:
                self.balance -= amt_withdrawal
                self.entertainment -= amt_withdrawal
                print("Withdrawal Successful")

            elif amt_withdrawal > self.Entertainment:
                print("Insufficient Entertainment Balance")
            
            else:
                print("Negative values cannot be withdrawn")

        else:  
            print('Invalid choice. Options are between 1-3 only')


budg = BudgetApp(float(input("Enter an amount to deposit: ")),
                 float(input("What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to food: ")), 
                 float(input("What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to cloth: ")),
                 float(input("What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to Entertainment: ")))
budg.withdrawal()
```

**Test Run**

```
Enter an amount to deposit: 100
What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to food: 40
What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to cloth: 30
What percentage of total amount do you want to allocate to Entertainment: 30

        Which Budget Category do you want to withdraw from?: 
            Please Enter:
                1 for Food (balance: 40.00)
                2 for Cloth (balance: 30.00)
                3 for Entertainment (balance: 30.00)1
How Much do you want to withdraw: 25
Withdrawal Successful
```